# How to get multipartentity from httpservletrequest

Tags: java, web-services, spring, apache, tomcat

I am trying to invoke a webservice from java spring controller. Below is the code

```
private void storeImages(MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest) {
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(
                    "http://localhost:8080/dream/storeimages.htm");
    MultipartFile multipartFile1 = multipartRequest.getFile("file1");
    MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity(
                    HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    multipartEntity.addPart("file1",
                    new ByteArrayBody(multipartFile1.getBytes(),
                                    multipartFile1.getContentType(),
                                    multipartFile1.getOriginalFilename()));
    postRequest.setEntity(multipartEntity);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 201) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

Above is just partial code. I am trying to determine how to retrieve this on the server side. On the server side i have the following Spring controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/storeimages.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView postItem(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) {
    logger.info("Inside /secure/additem/postitem.htm");
    try {
        // How to get the MultipartEntity object here. More specifically i
        // want to get back the Byte array from it
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new ModelAndView("success");
}
```

I executed this code and my control is going to the server side. But i am stuck on how to get back the byte array from the multipartentity object.

Edited requirement:
Here is the requirement. User uploads the images from website (This is done and working) The control goes to the Spring controller after form submit (This is done and working) In Spring controller I am using Multipart to get the content of the form. (This is done and working) Now i want to call a webservices which will send the image byte array to image server.(This needs to be done) On the image server, i want to receive this webservice request get all the fields from HTTPServlerRequest, store the images and return(This needs to be done)

Comment: What Servlet version are you targeting? Since servlet 3.0 HttpServletRequest has had a [getParts()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPart(java.lang.String)) method that can subsequently be used to get an InputStream.

Comment: How do i check if i am using Servlet 3.0. I am using tomcat 7. I have tried writing this but does not seem to work. The List size is 0.

         List<Part> formData = new ArrayList(request.getParts());
         Part part = formData.get(0);
         String parameterName = part.getName();
         logger.info("STORC IMAGES - " + parameterName);

Comment: @user1241438Ö Tomcat 7 is a Servlet 3.0 Container

Answer (score 7):

Finally resolved it. Here is what worked for me.

Client side

```
private void storeImages(HashMap<String, MultipartFile> imageList) {
    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/dream/storeimages.htm");

        MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

        Set set = imageList.entrySet(); 
        Iterator i = set.iterator(); 
        while(i.hasNext()) { 
            Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next(); 
            String fileName = (String)me.getKey();
            MultipartFile multipartFile = (MultipartFile)me.getValue();
            multipartEntity.addPart(fileName, new ByteArrayBody(multipartFile.getBytes(), 
                    multipartFile.getContentType(), multipartFile.getOriginalFilename()));
        } 
        postRequest.setEntity(multipartEntity);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);

        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));

        String output;
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            logger.info("Webservices output - " + output);
        }
        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Server side

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/storeimages.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void storeimages(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{
    logger.info("Inside /secure/additem/postitem.htm");
    try
    {
        //List<Part> formData = new ArrayList(request.getParts());
        //Part part = formData.get(0);
        //Part part = request.getPart("file1");
        //String parameterName = part.getName();
        //logger.info("STORC IMAGES - " + parameterName);
        MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request;

        Set set = multipartRequest.getFileMap().entrySet(); 
        Iterator i = set.iterator(); 
        while(i.hasNext()) { 
            Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next(); 
            String fileName = (String)me.getKey();
            MultipartFile multipartFile = (MultipartFile)me.getValue();
            logger.info("Original fileName - " + multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
            logger.info("fileName - " + fileName);
            writeToDisk(fileName, multipartFile);
        } 
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void writeToDisk(String filename, MultipartFile multipartFile)
{
    try
    {
        String fullFileName = Configuration.getProperty("ImageDirectory") + filename;
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fullFileName);
        fos.write(multipartFile.getBytes());
        fos.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my project, we used to use [MultipartParser](http://www.servlets.com/cos/javadoc/com/oreilly/servlet/multipart/MultipartParser.html) from com.oreilly.servlets to handle `HttpServletRequests` corresponding to `multipart` requests, as follows:

```
// Should be able to handle multipart requests upto 1GB size.
MultipartParser parser = new MultipartParser(aReq, 1024 * 1024 * 1024);
// If the content type is not multipart/form-data, this will be null.
if (parser != null) {
    Part part;
    while ((part = parser.readNextPart()) != null) {
        if (part instanceof FilePart) {
            // This is an attachment or an uploaded file.
        }
        else if (part instanceof ParamPart) {
            // This is request parameter from the query string
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing all that by hand, you can use Springs Mutlipart support

The controller can work like this (This example use a command object to store additional user inputs -- (this is an example from an working project)).

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView create(@Valid final DocumentCreateCommand documentCreateCommand,
        final BindingResult bindingResult) throws IOException {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
      return new ModelAndView("documents/create", "documentCreateCommand", documentCreateCommand);            
    } else {            
        Document document = this.documentService.storeDocument(
               documentCreateCommand.getContent().getBytes(),
               StringUtils.getFilename(StringUtils.cleanPath(documentCreateCommand.getContent().getOriginalFilename())));
               //org.springframework.util.StringUtils

        return redirectToShow(document);
    }
}


@ScriptAssert(script = "_this.content.size>0", lang = "javascript", message = "{validation.Document.message.notDefined}")
public class DocumentCreateCommand {
    @NotNull private org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile content;       
    Getter/Setter
}
```

To enable Spring Multipart support you need to configure some stuff:

web.xml (Add org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter after CharacterEncodingFilter and before HttpMethodFilter)

```
 <filter>
    <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter</filter-class>
    <!-- uses the bean: filterMultipartResolver -->
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

In your Spring Configuration for the CORE (not MVC Servlet) of your application add this

```
<!-- allows for integration of file upload functionality, used by an filter configured in the web.xml -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" id="filterMultipartResolver" name="filterMultipartResolver">
     <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000000"/>
</bean>
```

Then you also need the commons fileupload libary, because the Spring MultipartFile is just some kind of Addapter

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

For some more Details:
@See [Spring Reference, Chapter 15.8 Spring's multipart (fileupload) support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart)

Comment: From my website when the user uploads the images, i am already using multipart in my controller to get the files. Currently i am storing images in DB, but now i decided i can call a webservice to pass these images to another server which stores only images. SO i need to create a webservices request which will have images and then want to retrieve it on the server side where i want to store images. The above solution does not seem to address it.

Comment: @user1241438: I was not able to derive this requirements from your question.

Comment: Here is the requirement. 
User uploads the images from website (This is done and working)
The control goes to the Spring controller after form submit (This is done and working)
In Spring controller I am using Multipart to get the content of the form. (This is done and working)
Now i want to call a webservices which will send the image byte array to image server.(This needs to be done)
On the image server, i want to receive this webservice request get all the fields from HTTPServlerRequest, store the images and return(This needs to be done)

Comment: @user1241438 Update your question with that requirement!

Answer (score 0):

to deal with spring files to the controller. you need to indicate,  in your app-config.xml as follows:

```
    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>
```

and  treat code as follows

```
    MultipartEntityBuilder paramsBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    Charset chars = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    paramsBuilder.setCharset(chars);

    if (null != obj.getFile()){
    FileBody fb = new FileBody(obj.getFile());
    paramsBuilder.addPart("file", fb);
    }
```

and this for red multipart

```
private File getFile(MultipartFile file) {

    try {
        File fichero = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
        fichero.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fichero);
        fos.write(file.getBytes());
        fos.close();
        return fichero;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

I hope this helps.