# Request-Body(req.body) shows value but Request-QueryParams(req.queryParams) shows null value?

Tags: java, node.js, vue.js, axios, spark-java

I have used vuejs-axios to take data from client side and post it to server side. In server side I have used java wherby I used SparkJAVA Framework to handle request-response.
The below mentioned block of code is what I have used to post Form-Data from vuejs to java.

```
const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("name", this.name);
  formData.append("address", this.address);
  console.log(formData);
  axios
    .post("http://localhost:1234/formData", formData)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

Below mentioned code is used to parse FormData obtained from vuejs.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Spark.port(1234);
    Main.apply();

    get("/", (req, res) -> {
        return new ModelAndView(null, "StartPage.ftl");
    }, new FreeMarkerEngine());

    post("/formData", (req, res) -> {
        return FormController.showFormData(req, res);
    });
}

public class FormController {

    public static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(FormController.class);

    public static String showFormData(Request req, Response res) {
    System.out.println("Data body: " + req.body());
    System.out.println("Name: " + req.queryParams("name"));
    System.out.println("Address: " + req.queryParams("address"));

    return "Well Done!!!";
}
}
```

Below mentioned is the output:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"
Daniel
------WebKitFormBoundarydSA5AgIIhlMNCqA2

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="address"
New York
------WebKitFormBoundarydSA5AgIIhlMNCqA2--

Name: null
Address: null
```

I am getting response in **req.body()** but not in **req.queryParams()**.Why?
Also the reponse from **req.body()** looks a bit unusual.

Comment: looks like *multipart form data*

Comment: Would you explain on that? I went through multipart form data but couldn't get way to solve my issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127531/how-to-get-multipartentity-from-httpservletrequest

Answer (score 0):

Thats because `req.queryParams` is used to get URL params. Example: http://localhost:1234/formData?name=Bruno&address=earth. Try to use this example from the [official documentation of Spark Java](http://sparkjava.com/documentation#examples-and-faq). Here, it teaches you how to get a file from a multipart. It might work with some changes.