# Servlet receives null values after uploading a file

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets, file-upload, multipartform-data

I have a Java web application that includes a file upload feature. The HTML form `fileUpload.html` allows users to select and upload a file to the server. The form action is set to a servlet `ServletFileUpload.java` to process the uploaded file.

Here is the code mentioned above:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Datei Upload</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Dateien hochladen</h1>
    <form action="../fileUpload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <label for="name">Anzeigename:</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required /><br />

      <label for="expirationDate">Ablaufdatum:</label>
      <input
        type="date"
        name="expirationDate"
        id="expirationDate"
        required
      /><br />

      <label for="category">Kategorie:</label>
      <select name="category" id="category" required>
        <option value="" disabled>Wählen Sie eine Kategorie aus</option>
        <option value="aushang1">Aushang 1</option>
        <option value="aushang2">Aushang 2</option>
        <option value="vorschriften">Sicherheitsvorschriften</option>
        <option value="notfaelle">Notfälle</option>
        <option value="organisation">Organisation</option>
        <option value="anlagenleistung">Anlagenleistung</option>
        <option value="abfuellplan">Abfüllplan</option>
        <option value="schichtplan">Schichtplan</option>
        <option value="jahresplanung">Jahresplanung</option>
      </select>
      <br />

      <label for="pdfFile">Wählen Sie eine PDF aus:</label>
      <input type="file" name="pdfFile"  id="pdfFile" accept=".pdf"required><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="PDF hochladen">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

```java
@WebServlet("/fileUpload")
public class ServletFileUpload extends HttpServlet {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ServletFileUpload.class);

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        logger.debug("Name: {}, Expiration Date: {}, Category: {}",
                request.getParameter("name"),
                request.getParameter("expirationDate"),
                request.getParameter("category"));
    }
```

The problem I'm facing is that the `FileUpload.java` servlet doesn't seem to receive any data from the HTML form. When I submit the form, this is what gets logged:

> 15:38:19.860 [http-nio-8081-exec-51] DEBUG de.http.ServletFileUpload - Name: null, Expiration Date: null, Category: null

When submitting the form, I can see in the developer tools that the values in the form should be correct.

I'm using Tomcat 10.1 but when using Tomcat 9 I get the same results.
In the catalina.log I can't find anything related to this issue.

When changing the action-reference in HTML or the `@WebServlet` in Java I still run into the same problem.

Hopefully, somebody has an idea, what is wrong here.

Comment: Sounds like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65584370/how-to-retrieve-multipart-form-data-from-httpservletrequest-in-struts2

Comment: As the commenter before already suggested: I think your form is submitted as multipartform => you need to handle the incoming data a bit different. Maybe this also helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127531/how-to-get-multipartentity-from-httpservletrequest

Comment: For a multipart submission, you probably need to use the [getPart](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPart-java.lang.String-) method of HttpServletRequest rather than getParameter.  Read string values from getInputStream and use getContentType to determine the Charset of the bytes in that InputStream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this way, you will not be able to get parameters from the request.  The `multipart/form-data` content type makes it necessary to parse the request body in parts.  That is, if you are trying to get parameters using [`ServletRequest.getParameter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)):

> Returns the value of the query parameter as `String` or `null` if
> parameter does not exist.  Request parameters - additional information,
> sent with the request.  For HTTP servlets, the parameters are contained in
> the query line or in the body of the request where the form data is located.

then you get `null` because the request body has a different format, and the above method works if the request body has the format `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

---

More detailed information about [the `POST` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST):

> The HTTP `POST` method sends data to the server.  Request body type
> indicated by the `Content-Type` header.
>
> The difference between `PUT` and `POST` is that `PUT` is
> idempotent: calling it one or more times in a row has the same effect
> effect (which is not a side effect), where sequential
> an identical `POST` may have additional effects, e.g.
> transmit the same data several times.
>
> A `POST` request is usually sent via an HTML form and results in
> changes on the server.  In this case, the content type is selected by
> placing the appropriate string in the element's `enctype` attribute
> `<form>` or `formenctype` attribute of `<input>` elements or
> `<button>`:
>
> - `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`: keys and values ​​are encoded
>   in key tuples separated by `&`, with `=` between key and
>   meaning.  Non-alphanumeric characters in both keys and values
>   encoded as a percentage: this is the reason why this type is not suitable
>   for use with binary data (use instead
>   `multipart/form-data`);
> - `multipart/form-data`;
> - `text/plain`.

---

In order to be able to get parameters and parts of files from a request, you can use the [`@MultipartConfig`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/MultipartConfig.html) annotation:

> An annotation that can be placed on the `Servlet` class indicating
> that servlet instances expect requests matching the type
> MIME with `multipart/form-data`.
>
> Servlets annotated with `MultipartConfig` can retrieve
> `Part` components of a given `multipart/form-data` request, calling
> `getPart()` or `getParts()`.

---

You can also read about the `@MultipartConfig` annotation in the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gmhal.html).

In which you can also find [an example of `fileupload`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glraq.html) using this annotation.