# File uploaded from jsp is not making it to servlet

Tags: html, forms, jsp, servlets

I am attempting to upload a csv file from my JSP and used in the servlet request. I keep getting an exception in the servlet and it appears the file doesn't make it that far.

Here's part of my JSP. I've left out unnecessary parts:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<TABLE>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form action="CIServlet" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="cN"
                       value="<%= request.getAttribute("cN") %>">
                Upload: <input type="file" name="fileName"  enctype="multipart/form data">
                <input type="submit" id="uploadFile" name="uploadFile" value="Upload CSV file">
            </form>
        </td>
    <tr>

</TABLE>
</body>
```

My servlet looks like this:

```
@WebServlet(name = "CIServlet", value = "/CIServlet")
@MultipartConfig
public class CIServletextends HttpServlet {

@Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
try {
                Part filePart = request.getPart("fileName");
} catch (IOException e) {
                response.getWriter().write("Failed to process CSV content due to " + e);
            } catch (ServletException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

When I submit the form, I get an exception:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: The request content-type is not a multipart/form-data

`request.getPart("fileName")` is `null` when debugging.  However if I evaluate `request.getParameter("fileName")` it has the file name.

I'm expecting `request.getPart()` to not be `null`. I'm using `enctype="multipart/form data"` on the file input. I'm also using `@MultipartConfig` annotation on my Servlet.

I've also made sure there's no JavaScript in my JSP that could be erasing the `enctype`.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute `enctype="multipart/form data"` should be set on `<form>` tag, not on the file input.

```xml
<form action="CIServlet" enctype="multipart/form data" method="post">
          <input type="hidden" name="cN" value="<%= request.getAttribute("cN") %>">
  Upload: <input type="file" name="fileName">
          <input type="submit" id="uploadFile" name="uploadFile" value="Upload CSV file">
</form>
```

---

If you need more information how to upload a file using servlet see [Servlet receives null values after uploading a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77238902/573032).

> In order to be able to get parameters and parts of files from a request, you can use the `@MultipartConfig` annotation:
>
> > An annotation that can be placed on the `Servlet` class indicating
> > that servlet instances expect requests matching the type
> > MIME with `multipart/form-data`.
> >
> > Servlets annotated with `MultipartConfig` can retrieve
> > `Part` components of a given `multipart/form-data` request, calling
> > `getPart()` or `getParts()`.